# Changing the functionality of numbers in JS (for educational purposes)

Tags: javascript, numbers, metaprogramming

I was wondering if there was some way to change the `Number` object (or other objects) so that when expressions like `4(3 - 1)` are ran, instead of throwing an error, the result is the same as `4 * (3 - 1)` or `8`. Maybe along the lines of turning numbers into functions? If anyone knows of any methods (other than changing the coding editor directly) I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Number objects, that's the JavaScript parser, since it's invalid syntax. If you allowed numbers to be callable, you'd have to write it as `Number(3)(3 - 1)`

Comment: There's no built-in way to customize the parser. It's generally done using transpilers like TypeScript and Babel.

Comment: Does that mean there is a way to get the functionality I want using TypeScript? Or would I be able to build some sort of custom parser for JavaScript that can handle this?

Comment: No, it means that you can use the same technology as TypeScript to create a language that's similar to JavaScript but includes your changes.

Comment: There is no practical way to supplant the parser with your own. JavaScript is an extremely complicated language to parse, and even if it weren't it's just a truly outlandish concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** make primitives callable in JavaScript.

If you want to make an evaluator that allows brackets, make something like

```
function myEval(text) {
  // 123(234)567 => 123 * (234)567
  text = text.replaceAll(/(\d) *\(/g, '$1 * (')
  // 123(234)567 => 123(234) * 567
  text = text.replaceAll(/\) *(\d)/g, ') * $1')
  return eval(text)
}
```

Comment: @Ryan also consider smth like https://cortexjs.io/compute-engine/demo/ if you need actual math rather then JS code